# Probability - Expected value of a geometric R.V. which connects to a result of a dice roll

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

A fair dice is rolled and the result and written down, Then the dice is rolled repeatedly (independently) untill the first occurence of a result bigger or equal to the result we've written down.

Find the expected value of the total number of dice rolls, including the first.

My attempt was to define a geometric RV $N$~$Geo(1-\frac {x-1}{6})$
, where $x$ is the result of the first roll.

So $N$ is the number of rolls we did untill we got a number bigger or equal to $x$, so we're looking for $E[N+1]$ in order to also count the first roll.

and with that:
$$
E[N+1]=E[N]+E[1]=1+1\cdot (1-\frac {1-1}{6})+ \ldots +6\cdot (1-\frac {6-1}{6})=\frac {31}{3}
$$

Which I'm not sure on how to confirm this answer, in general I feel like I'm missing something big due to the fact that $x$ takes on values $\in \\{1,\ldots,6\\}$ which directly affects the argument we're placing as $p$ in the geometric distribution.

Comment: Try conditioning on the outcome of the first toss.

Comment: Should I define the first roll to be a discrete uniform r.v. with values $1 ,\ldots ,6$?

Comment: Note that your answer seems far too high.  Even if you get a $6$ on the first try, you only expect $7$.

Comment: Sure.  A fair die comes up one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ uniformly.

Comment: This is an apporach I had in mind, but was not sure how to move on with.
I'll update the question once I made progress/went down this path and got stuck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conditional expectation problem, where we condition the expected value based on the initial roll.

Let's call $X$ the total number of rolls and $R1$ the value rolled on the first roll.

$E[X | R1 = 1] = 1 + 1 = 2$

$E[X | R1 = 2] = 1 + \frac65 = \frac{11}5$

$E[X | R1 = 3] = 1 + \frac32 = \frac{5}2$

$E[X | R1 = 4] = 1 + 2 = 3$

$E[X | R1 = 5] = 1 + 3 = 4$

$E[X | R1 = 6] = 1 + 6 = 7$

All of these have a $\frac16$ chance of occuring thus:
$E[X] = \frac16(2 + \frac{11}5 + \frac52 + 3 + 4 + 7) = 3.45$

Comment: This is just the thing I was looking for. conditional expectation did not come to mind when i thought about this, even though I knew there was a conditional part of the calculation.  
Thank you for your time!   

btw, we're adding $1$ to every $E[X|R1=i]$ in order to take into consideration the first roll? (where $R=i$ was discoverd)

Comment: Glad I could help! And correct, the 1 is being added to take the first roll into consideration. The second addend is the expected number of rolls to obtain a value of $i$ or higher (mean of geometric distribution)